# VS Code terminal.integrated.inheritEnv flag in debug mode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have `"terminal.integrated.inheritEnv": false` in my `settings.json` and it works for terminals that I start.

However it does not apply to terminals started when I start debugging. How to fix this issue?

Environment:

- Linux, VSCode 1.84.2
- C++, VS code extension: "C/C++ IntelliSense, debugging, and code browsing"
- VS Code configuration type: "cppdbg", uses gdb underneath

Comment: [discussion raised](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/discussions/11689). I'll post an answer here once maintainers reply with an answer there.